# Menuentry in 40_custom file problem

Tags: grub2

I have a menuentry problem in my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop ISO" {
loopback loop /home/simia/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/home/simia/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso noeject noprompt splash --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop amd64 ISO" {
loopback loop /home/simia/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/home/simia/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso noeject noprompt splash --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop amd64 ISO" {
loopback loop /home/simia/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/home/simia/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso noeject noprompt splash --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

`Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop ISO` and `Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop amd64 ISO` from the menu work fine but not the `Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop amd64 ISO` menuentry, it just restarts the computer. What is the problem? Iso files have the same flags -rw-r--r-- 1 simia simia and the sha256sums are right.

**UPDATE**

If I have this menuentry:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 19.10 ISO" {
set isofile="/home/simia/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,2)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

then grub2 writes `error: file not found`, by other (hd0,1, hd0,3, hd0,4) parameters it writes `error: no such partition`.

```
#blkid
/dev/sda2: UUID="B498-74ED" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="d11a7607-b5d5-441b-b159-c539cf105694" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="92148748-73ad-489f-8228-ed7e700adf30" TYPE="ext4"

#fdisk -l
Диск /dev/sda: 500.1 Гб, 500107862016 байт
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = циліндри of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00066d16

Пристрій Завант  Початок     Кінець     Блоків  Ід  Система
/dev/sda1             310       59626   476463802+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda2   *       59627       60801     9438187+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda5             310       58739   469338943+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6           58740       59626     7124796   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Those are all EoL versions of Ubuntu. Please only use current versions. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: With Ubuntu 20.04 it is the same thing. @oldfred

Comment: I find getting path correct & some of the changes in names make a difference on whether it works or not. ISO boot & link to examples
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
more examples
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c
Both 20.04 and 20.10 have worked for me. But some have now needed this: `rmmod tpm` Other  flavors have given error on using that parameter, but still work.